# Is there a modulus operator for Integers in the OCaml bindings for Z3?

Tags: ocaml, z3

I'm looking through the `Z3.Arithmetic` module, and I do not see any `mk_modulus` or similar function provided. Is there a binding for the `mod` operator in Z3?

I can internally build a term `(x - ((x / 2) * 2))`, but if there's a binding for `mod`, I would prefer it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for the `mk_mod` function, found here:

https://github.com/Z3Prover/z3/blob/a1f484fa35d171131f294e6c1b415b897fdb99df/src/api/ml/z3.mli#L1186-L1188

There's also `mk_rem`, right next to `mk_mod`, if that's what you'd need as well.

Comment: I get an `Error: Unbound value Arithmetic.mk_mod`. My ocaml bindings seem to match the ones found here: https://z3prover.github.io/api/html/ml/Z3.Arithmetic.html

Comment: Use this module https://z3prover.github.io/api/html/ml/Z3.Arithmetic.Integer.html. Note the extra indirection `Arithmetic.Integer.mk_mod`

Comment: Ah! thank you very much! I had not realised the `mod` is only an Integer operation. I thought it applied to Reals too.

Comment: Modulus/reminder doesn't make sense for `Real`s: They'd always be `0`. (Division is exact for reals.) If you use floating-point, however, you can use `rem` for them. See `mk_rem` in  https://z3prover.github.io/api/html/ml/Z3.FloatingPoint.html